# Eclipse PyDev Code completion of dynamic class attributes?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, code-completion

I would like to get the code completion in Eclipse with PyDev for the attributes of a class which is dynamically generated.

Basically, I have a class which is defined by reading out an XML document. Depending on what is written in this XML document, the class has different attributes dynamically defined (the XML-tags).

I would like to activate the code completion after calling the constructor of the class in my code.

The problem I see is that I have no control on the attributes of the class, which means : before running the code, I have no idea which attributes might be available. Does anyone have an idea ?

I tried to add the library to the Forces-Built In without success.

Regards

Comment: How does one write code for a class whose attributes are unknown ahead of time? Is every statement with an attribute access reference in a `try/except`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, PyDev can't really guess what you have if by looking at the code you don't know yourself ;)

Still, PyDev allows you to give it skeletons which can be used for code-completion purposes, so, an option here would be parsing the xml yourself and creating a class structure with attributes/methods as needed and ask PyDev to use that to give you completions.

You can see the Interpreter Configuration on the Getting Started manual: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-PredefinedCompletions for info on how to actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found yersterday some example with pypredef, and I started with this solution, and for now on it works well.

The only thing you need to care about is the identation. It looks like when you are implementing your .pypredef in Eclipse, you need to use 4 spacings als ident instead of a tab.